# Is it possible to do fast unchecked cast of structs in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, pointers, struct

Suppose you have two structs that have exactly the same memory layout. Is it possible to do a very fast unchecked memory cast from one to the other in C#/.NET?

```
//my code base
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct VectorA
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
}

//defined by a third party library
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct VectorB
{
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
}

//somewhere else in my code
var vectorA = new VectorA();

//then calling a method from the library
MethodFromThirdPartyLibrary((VectorB)vectorA); //compiler error
```

Of course it should be faster as a method that assigns the data fields and creates a new copy in memory.

Also: The 3d vector is only an example, same problem for matrices which is 16 floats and Vector2, Vector4, ...

**EDIT:** Improved code with more comments and better usage example.

Comment: Probably `VectorB b = *(VectorB*)&a;` (in unsafe context) should do.

Comment: @Evk but that wouldn't be faster than `vectorB.x = vectorA.x; ... ` , would it?

Comment: See also [Unsafe Code and Pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/index) (read: use at own risk; don't complain if your machine is suddenly set on fire when using this)

Comment: @Freggar if you already have `vectorB` to set fields - you already allocated memory (with all values 0). But OP wants without new copy, as I understand. The above statement, I think, doesn't make any copies or allocations. `VectorB` now points to the same memory `VectorA` does. Though I can be wrong in that. `VecAToB` method signature in question, as I understand, already violates what is being asked.

Comment: Why do you have 2 identical types? I'm curious what the use case is here.

Comment: @itsme86 it's not unsual that you have different Libraries with the same kind of structs. Although not identical `System.Drawing.Point` and `System.Windows.Point` would be an example in .NET (I know that one is of `ints` an the other is of `doubles`) but still

Comment: @Freggar It is for me.

Comment: Using BenchmarkDotNet, it *seems* like copying the values (`vB.a = vA.x; vB.b = vA.y; vB.c = vA.z`) is ever so slightly faster than the pointer way (`VectorB vB = *(VectorB*)&vA;`) **in this case**. Tested with a list of 100 and 1000 randomly generated items of `VectorA` the difference was less than 10% and getting smaller with more items.

Comment: @Corak you didn't use function signature from question for this test? Because it involves useless (for pointer method) allocation of vector b.

Comment: I've done an edit of the code with a better usage example.

Comment: @Evk - I even used it "directly" as `VectorB vB = *(VectorB*)&vA;` while copying was done in a method, like the example of keith with `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]`. -- which might explain the difference getting smaller and smaller with more items, because then the overhead of calling the copy method becomes relevant?

Comment: @Corak maybe you can post your benchmark somewhere? Of course it's easy to code it myself, but since you already did...

Comment: @Evk - Sorry, did it on work pc (after hours ^_^) and am at home for the weekend right now.

Answer (score 0):

Why would it be faster? Would it be faster in C++ than writing the copy explicitly as in C#? Remember, you only have 3 x 32-bit numbers you want to copy from one place to another, so it's not exactly a good fit for vectorization.

It's likely if you had an array of these structures that you could get some speed up using vectorized load/stores in an unrolled loop in assembler. But you've not stated that in the question.

The main overhead here is probably the method call, rather than the assignment:

```
static void VecAToB(ref VectorA vectorA, ref VectorB vectorB)
{
    vectorB.x = vectorA.a;
    vectorB.y = vectorA.b;
    vectorB.z = vectorA.c;
}
```

You might like to try:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
static void VecAToB(ref VectorA vectorA, ref VectorB vectorB)
{
    vectorB.x = vectorA.a;
    vectorB.y = vectorA.b;
    vectorB.z = vectorA.c;
}
```